# Incorrect Yaw from imu_filter_magwick at ENU and NED

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

Currently, I am using a PhidgetSpatial 3/3/3 1042. However, I encounter strange yaw output when passing the reading of my IMU to imu_filter_magwick.

### 1

When I set "world_frame" to "ned", my yaw value (after subscribe to /imu/rpy/filtered) gives 0 degree when facing **east** and
-90 degree when facing **north**.  On the other hand, If I select "enu", my yaw value is 0 when facing **north**, and -90 when facing **east**.

Originally, base on my reading from https://answers.ros.org/question/364998/should-imu-frame-follow-the-red-east-green-north-and-blue-up-convention/  I was expecting in 'ENU', yaw = 0 when face **east**, and yaw=-90 when face **north**. And in "NED" mode, yaw =0 when face **north** and yaw=90 when face **east**

### 2

Aside from the weird 90 degree offset. Something I find also strange.
In "NED" mode,my  yaw = 0 +/- 5 degree when face **east**. However, my yaw = -75 degree when facing North.
On the other hand, yaw = 180 degree when face **west**, yaw = 75 when face **south**.

Thus, my question is why is the yaw offset rather huge when face **south** and **north**.

### Atempt

1. Tried to calibrate IMU with the company's firmware.

## Config file

```
imu_filter:
  ros__parameters:
    stateless: false
    use_mag: true
    publish_tf: true # pueublish /odom to imu_link
    reverse_tf: false
    fixed_frame: "odom"
    constant_dt: 0.0
    publish_debug_topics: false
    world_frame: "ned"
    gain: 0.1
    zeta: 0.0
    mag_bias_x: 0.0
    mag_bias_y: 0.0
    mag_bias_z: 0.0
    orientation_stddev: 0.1
    publish_debug_topics: true
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/411463/incorrect-yaw-from-imu_filter_magwick-at-enu-and-ned/) by [sdu568](https://answers.ros.org/users/103946/sdu568/) on ROS Answers with karma: 45 on 2023-01-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So I realized what I wrong.

The X-axis for the imu is pointing to the left side, not pointing forward.
Is a very naive mistake of mine.

---

Originally posted by [sdu568](https://answers.ros.org/users/103946/sdu568/) with karma: 45 on 2023-01-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0